# In Mercurial, How to check the revision log of a specific folder?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

So here is an example folder hierarchy:

```
c:\MyProject
c:\MyProject\Folder1
c:\Myproject\Folder2
```

In SVN, If I am only interested in looking at the history of changes in `c:\MyProject\Folder1` I could just navigate to that folder, right click and view log.

With Mercurial doing the same thing shows all the changes in the entire MyProject.   Is there a way to filter out and show me only changes in `Folder1` (And its sub-folders) ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It pretty much works as you would expect, same as for `svn log`:

```
hg log c:\MyProject\Folder1
```

Comment: Does this only work for `hg log`? I was hoping to use something like `hg tags` but it's not working as I expected.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell To see the revisions for a tag, try `hg log -r "ancestor(tagname)"`.

Comment: note that this works as long as your current directory is not inside another mercurial project (I learned it the hard way)

Comment: This appears to be recursive starting from the specified folder as the root. How can you do it just to the contents of "Folder1" only?

Answer (score 5):

In TortoiseHG, you right-click on `Folder1` and open the Repository Explorer from there.
This automatically sets the filter in the Repository Explorer to show only the history of this folder.

Something similar is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155367/searching-a-mercurial-repository-tortoisehg) (for single files instead of folders, but you get the idea...)

Comment: I don't get "Repository Explorer" as an option when I right-click on a folder.

Comment: It was called "Repository Explorer" in 2010. From version 2.0 on, it's called "Hg Workbench".

Comment: Ah yes, but I still don't get Hg Workbench when I right-click on a folder. I get it when I the blank space in a folder, but not when clicking on a folder that's in a repo.

Comment: And  when you click on the folder that contains the repo? (in other words, the parent folder of the `.hg` folder)

Comment: Clicking on the folder that contains the repo does give me Hg Workbench. I realised I'm running v2.6.2 and v3.0 is out so I'll see if upgrading to that gives me the option.

Comment: If you want to see all the logged fields, such as date and time, you will need to right click the header of the log list (the one that by default contains "Graph", "Rev", "Branch" etc) and click "Choose Log Columns"

Answer (score 2):

In the new style tortoise hg (Hg Workbench) you can achieve this by right clicking and selecting `TortoiseHg => Revision History` on a folder in your repo.

What this actually does is filter (ctrl+s) like this `file('path:some/relative/path')`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but: if you installed only TortoiseHg with no explorer extensions, then you can press Ctrl-S in it and enter the revision query `file("path:SOME/PATH")`.